# maven compilation - error log4j

Tags: maven, log4j, pom.xml

i'm building java application and suddenly i found problem with compilation:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project sonda: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] ..../service/UserService.java:[7,23] package org.apache.log4j does not exist
```

But i was building this application before and everything was ok. Additionally, when i run this application under Eclipse using tomcat, it's running well.

In pom i have:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change the scope of the log4j dependency to compile or remove it.

Comment: <scope>compile</scope>, helpful for me too.

Comment: In most of the cases use this. either make scope as compile instead of runtime or remove it

Answer (score 8):

I ran into exactly the same problem:

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Build error: `package org.apache.log4j does not exist`

Root cause: I needed to build my project against an older JRE (JRE 1.5.x); the current libraries are apparently incompatible.

Solution: back-rev to an older version of log4j.jar:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

<= Compiles successfully!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error while migrating from log4j 1.x to log4j 2.x and realized I still had some code that only worked with 1.x. Instead of refactoring code I added this dependency to my pom.xml in order to maintain compatibility.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you! I too was trying to update from 1.x to 2.x because Github was telling me there were vulnerabilities with the 1.x version I was using.   Changing the artifactId to what you have did the trick.

Comment: great! you finally solved my problem. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this in your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

replace it with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.15</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  
</dependency>
```

Comment: Won't this make log4j an actual dependency, and the author seems to be using a back end other than log4j and only would need the log4j API as specified in the original  pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Friend this type of problem occurs when you are used JRE, change the libraries of your project for Java JDK that the problem will be fixed and you can use slf4j.