# log4j package does not exist

Tags: java, maven

I'm running mvn install, getting below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile 

error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
```

In my project hierarchy I have log4j-1.2.15.jar added as a Referenced Libraries..not sure what I'm missing.

Part of POM file with log4j dependency (should I change the version to just say 1.2...or possible remove the scope below?):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667640/maven-compilation-error-log4j

Comment: is log4j configured as a maven dependency? Adding libraries to Eclipse's build path will not make them available to Maven.

Comment: I don't see the dependency in the project POM file

Comment: Have you tried adding the Log4j dependency in your pom?

Comment: I added the dependency into POM, now I'm getting this error.  Maybe the previous error corrected once I added to POM... not sure.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project1: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.title.proj:project1:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:1.2.15, org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:1.2.15: Could not find artifact org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:1.2.15 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

Comment: Updated my issue with the part of the POM file above

Comment: Still getting original error

Comment: May be you have some old/corrupted versions of `log4j` jar. In your `.m2` directory, if you find dependencies of `org.apache.logging`, delete them and do a `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For log4j I only use  this libraries:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This has an open vulnerability as mentioned in NVD https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-17571. Please don't use this.

According to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j, this artifact has been moved to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core.

Comment: I agree with the comment above (mentioning CVE-2019-17571)! This should not be marked as solution.

Answer (score 0):

At first, it can be related with some your customizations of the environment or with dependencies in your *.pom file ([Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin (default-compile) on project: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700576/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-compiler-plugin-default-c)). You need to check default installed "jre" to a jdk. Also ensure maven instalation and  , namely paths: `$JAVA_HOME` and `$M2_HOME`

for example the paths adjustments when you have linux:
[image]

When I execute the command: `echo $JAVA_HOME` I will have `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle` and appropriate path for maven

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse users this directly resolved this problem.  There is no need to re-install anything with maven installed in eclipse oxygen centos 6.  Vogella tutorial below says to resolve the dependency by adding the .jar via downloaded index at startup.  As identified above answer 1.2.17 is around the same solution that worked for me (1.2.15)  *You must launch eclipse in a terminal with JAVA_HOME set as mentioned above.*  Eclipse will handle the rest.

[How to use maven in eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html)

Identifies how to download the dependency list.  Once you setup your project you open the pom gui and select Dependencies.  You search for the above mentioned library select and add it.  During initial build, the dependent .jar is downloaded and configured dynamically via the pom.xml state injection, this is why no manual deleting or re-install is necessary.

**It is still not managed**-  To manage the dependency, i.e. add it to the pom, you select the item you just added and click manage and follow the prompts to add it the Dependency Management list.  This is an automatic pom addition from the gui - `

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.ecf</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15.v201012070815</version>
    </dependency>`
```

When the Dependency Management list is populated your library will display a (managed:version) tag in orange.

Start smiling, right click pom, run as maven build, the errors should be gone.