# error: package org.slf4j does not exist

Tags: java, netbeans, slf4j

I am attempting to create a program in Java using Netbeans. I am attempting to use org.slf4j. I think I have placed the sufficient amount of slf4j jar files in my CLASS PATH. I have placed slf4j-api, slf4j-jcl, slf4j-jdk14, slf4j-nop and slf4j-simple in my class path.

My question is: Am i placing the wrong jar files in my class path, the Zip file for the slf4j folder included a large amount of jar files. Why are there so many executable jar files included for SLF4J.

Ultimately, the program needs to compare 2 pdf files at a time and spit out an error message if the files are different. Would anyone know if there is anything out there that I can include so I don't have to deal with this SLF4J package.
Below is where I am attempting to run the package.

*import org.slf4j.Logger;*

*import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;*

Comment: Please add error exit. Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667640/maven-compilation-error-log4j

Comment: Hello Ruben, Thank you for your comment. I am in NetBeans for Java. I went into the Library and found the POM.XML file but i could not find anything for the log4j dependency, on top of that the pom.xml file is uneditable.

Comment: I have downloaded SLF4J, maybe it is different. SLF4J zip file has a whole bunch of different SLF4J sub folders. I placed almost all of them in the Main path. Changing the scope in the POM did not seem to fix the issue. I should download Apache log4j, any thoughts?

Comment: If you have a maven project you could try to put the files into local maven repository. When maven downloads dependencies usually puts the files into the user folder: {user folder}\.m2\repository\org\slf4j

Comment: How did you add the to your classpath? If you're talking about the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, forget about its existence. Most ways of running Java applications don't use it, and generally it makes things rather brittle for applications that do use it.

Answer (score 25):

Set Dependencies as follows.

In Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>version number</version>
</dependency>
```

In Gradle

```
dependencies {
   compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: 'version number'
}
```

Comment: Version 1.6.6 is pretty old. The current latest is 1.7.28.

Comment: Yeah, It's okay. We can add dependencies like that.

Comment: As of 26 May 2022, latest Stable version is 1.7.36.

Comment: Yeah. It is just for example. I have edited it to generic.

Answer (score 4):

In Gradle add the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28'
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.28'
```

The last one dependency needs to be added to Resolve "[Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder)"

Answer (score 3):

In build.gladle ( the second one ) look at dependencies and add this line:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.slf4j.api:1.7.2'
}
```